# Get attribute of child node XML - PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am building up a script using XML DOM and PHP

```
$troops = $xmlfile->getElementsByTagName("troops");

foreach( $troops as $troop ) {

    $sniper = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "sniper" );
    $otroop[0] = $sniper->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $riffle = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "riffle" );
    $otroop[1] = $riffle->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $riffle = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "shooter" );
    $otroop[2] = $riffle->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $riffle = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "missle" );
    $otroop[3] = $riffle->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $tank = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "tank" );
    $otroop[4] = $tank->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $bomber = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "bomber" );
    $otroop[5] = $bomber->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $patrol = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "patrol" );
    $otroop[6] = $patrol->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $surveillance = $troop->getElementsByTagName( "surveillance" );
    $otroop[7] = $surveillance->item(0)->nodeValue;

}
```

XML

```
<troops>
    <sniper level="5">2</sniper>
    <riffle level="0">0</riffle>
    <shooter level="0">0</shooter>
    <missle level="0">0</missle>
    <tank level="0">0</tank>
    <bomber level="0">0</bomber>
    <patrol level="0">0</patrol>
    <surveillance level="0">0</surveillance>
</troops>
```

I wanna be able to pull the level for each node as well i had tried

```
$oresearch[0] = $sniper->getAttribute("level");
```

but that doesn't work, any advice here would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In your code `$sniper` is a [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/domnodelist). You handle that correctly where you get the value of the first node:

```
$sniper->item(0)->nodeValue
```

For attributes of the first node you have to do it analogous:

```
$sniper->item(0)->getAttribute('level')
```